# How to implement a relational database and access it through mobile services from Android in Azure?

Tags: database, azure, mobile, service, relational

I have designed a database with two tables: Client and Bill

- User table has two columns: idUser and password.
- Bill table has three columns: idBill, date and description.

User table has an 1:n relationship with Bill table.
¿How can I implement this design in a SQL Server and then access data through Mobile Services from an Android device?

I tried to follow these steps:

1. Create a Mobile Service
2. Access admin panel in the new Mobile Service
3. In the “Data” tab, add Client table and Bill table
   But that it’s all. I cannot define a relationship (foreign key) between these tables.

Also, I tried to create the tables by T-SQL sentences but when I created it, it don´t appear in the mobile services admin panel “Data” tab.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Services doesn't consider or handle any foreign key constraints (i.e. a relationship from User to Bill).  However, you can enforce this constraint on your client side and by using the server side scripts to ensure data integrity / perform custom SQL statements.  I would recommend creating the User and Bill tables in the mobile Service portal (sounds like you already did that) and then start saving data from your client.  Mobile Services uses dynamic schematization to automatically add new columns to the DB for you.  You can still connect directly to the SQL database (via SQL Management Studio or the SQL Portal) and create the constraint if you want.  If you were to try doing something from the Mobile Service that would violate the constraint, an error will be thrown and you can either handle that in your server scripts or on your client side.